# Conda activate env works in bash but not fabric

Tags: python, ubuntu, fabric

I'm working with fabric and python 3.6 on on a ubuntu 16.04 VPS. If I ssh in and use bash I can do:

```
deploy@server:~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
python-devel             /home/deploy/miniconda3/envs/python-devel
test                     /home/deploy/miniconda3/envs/test
root                  *  /home/deploy/miniconda3

deploy@server:~$ source activate test
(test) deploy@server:~$
```

I have the following fabric function:

```
def _update_conda_env(site_folder, host):
......

    run(f'source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate test')
    run(f'~/miniconda3/bin/conda info --envs')
```

which gives output:

```
[deploy@mysite.org] run: source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate test
[deploy@mysite.org] run: ~/miniconda3/bin/conda info --envs
[deploy@mysite.org] out: # conda environments:
[deploy@mysite.org] out: #
[deploy@mysite.org] out: python-devel             /home/deploy/miniconda3/envs/python-devel
[deploy@mysite.org] out: test                     /home/deploy/miniconda3/envs/test
[deploy@mysite.org] out: root                  *  /home/deploy/miniconda3
[deploy@mysite.org] out: 
[deploy@mysite.org] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from deploy@mysite.org... done.
```

How can I get this working in fabric

Answer (score 1):

Your `activate` only stays active for one cycle unless you use `prefix`.

```
with prefix('source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate test'):
    run(f'~/miniconda3/bin/conda info --envs')
```

This way, everything in your run block will be prefixed with `source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate test &&`